# How to make diff command ignore certain lines of second file(bash)?

Tags: bash, shell-script, diff

For example:

file1.txt:

```
I need to buy apples.
I need to run the laundry.
I need to wash the dog.
I need to get the car detailed.
```

file2.txt

```
I need to buy apples.
I need to run the laundry.
I need to wash the car.
I need to get the car detailed.
```

file3.txt

```
I need to wash the car.
```

If I do `diff file1.txt file2.txt`,
the statements present in file3.txt should be ignored by diff command if it is present in file2.txt. So, in this case, there should be no difference.

Using ignore flag (`diff -I "$line"`) won't help since it finds pattern in both files.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't think there's a direct way - you'll have to strip off lines in file1 corresponding to those lines in file2.

Comment: @muru That was what came into my mind. But that seems to be a tough way. I am using diff command inside `if` condition so I thought first filter out the line from file2 and corresponding lines from file1 somehow and count the lines of `diff` output.

Comment: Please revise your question so it makes sense.  If "the statements present in file3.txt should be ignored by diff command if it is present in file2.txt", then you are logically comparing a four-line file to a three-line file, and so there ***is*** a difference.  Please state the rule that you want the answer to implement that would justify _not_ reporting that "I need to wash the dog." is present in file1.txt but not file2.txt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround would be to strip of the corresponding lines and then diff it. That's to say, both `file1` and `file2` would look like:

```
I need to buy apples.
I need to run the laundry.

I need to get the car detailed.
```

You can do this using a combination of `grep`, `perl` and `sed`:

```
$ lines_to_ignore=$(grep -nFf file3 file2 | perl -pe 's|^(\d+):.*|$1s/.//g;|')
$ echo $lines_to_ignore 
3s/.//g;
$ diff <(sed "$lines_to_ignore" file1) <(sed "$lines_to_ignore" file2)        
$ echo $?
0
```

- I use `grep` to get the matching lines (along with line numbers) in `file2`
- Then I use `perl` to get the line numbers from the `grep` output and make sed commands from them (`Ns/.//g` deletes every character on line N).
- Then I use process substitution to feed the result of `sed` running these commands on the files to `diff`.

Answer (score 2):

You could combine `diff` and `combine` here:

```
$ diff file1.txt <(combine file2.txt NOT file3.txt)
3d2
< I need to wash the dog.
```

Updated to reflect changes in OP.

Comment: "So, in this case, there should be no difference." - from question.

Comment: "the _statements present in file3.txt should be ignored_ by diff command if it is present in file2.txt. So, _in this case, there should be no difference_."

Comment: And how do you interpret that?

Comment: Sorry, question edited. The difference is only in third line.

Comment: This won't work then. How would you decide which entry correspondents to another changed entry? Are the line numbers fixed like in @muru`s example?

Answer (score 1):

use grep option to filter out line from file

```
$ diff f1 f2
3c3
< I need to wash the dog.
---
> I need to wash the car.
$ diff <( grep -v -f f3 -x f1) <( grep -v -f f3 -x f2)
3d2
< I need to wash the dog.
```

where

- `<( )` is a bash syntax to create a temporary file
- in grep

  - `-x` match whole lie
  - `-f f3` take patterm from file f3
  - `-v` show unmatched pattern

Comment: This looks good but the corresponding difference in `f1` should also be removed.

Answer (score 0):

`diff` might not be the right tool.  It sounds like you need to use [`comm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comm), which classifies each line as being in one file, the other file, or common to both.

The key limitation, though, is that `comm` requires both input files to be sorted